# MySQL How can I speed up this SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, optimization, select

I have a very large table of over 9 million rows and in my software I need to rapidly do select queries on it in a loop. The problem is that the queries take almost 4 seconds to complete. Here is one of the queries (they are all similar in that they all have the same WHERE clause that is slowing them down:

```
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM `04c1Tg0M`
WHERE `tried` = 0;
```

I'm using the tried column as a boolean. the value is either 1 or 0. Here is the EXPLAIN from that query:

```
--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | 04c1Tg0M | index | NULL          | pdex | 158     | NULL | 9275107 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `04c1Tg0M` (
    `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `tried` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `pdex` (`username`,`id`,`tried`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9275108 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is the output of show indes:

```
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| 04c1Tg0M |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |     9275107 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| 04c1Tg0M |          1 | pdex     |            1 | username    | A         |     9275107 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| 04c1Tg0M |          1 | pdex     |            2 | id          | A         |     9275107 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| 04c1Tg0M |          1 | pdex     |            3 | tried       | A         |     9275107 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

And here is the output from the query in question:

```
+---------+
| MIN(id) |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
1 row in set (3.76 sec)
```

I need to drastically reduce the query time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT`? Do you know what percentage of the rows have `tried = 0` versus `tried = 1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add an index on `(tried, id)`.

You already added an index on `(username,id,tried)` but this index cannot be used efficiently for the query you wrote because the field `tried` is not the first item in the index.

---

From the manual page [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> MySQL uses indexes for these operations:
>
> - To find the `MIN()` or `MAX()` value for a specific indexed column `key_col`. This is optimized by a preprocessor that checks whether you are using `WHERE key_part_N = constant` on all key parts that occur before `key_col` in the index. In this case, MySQL does a single key lookup for each `MIN()` or `MAX()` expression and replaces it with a constant. If all expressions are replaced with constants, the query returns at once. For example:
>
>   SELECT MIN(key_part2),MAX(key_part2)
>      FROM tbl_name WHERE key_part1=10;

Note in particular that the `WHERE` clause must refer to columns that occur *before* the column for which you wish to calculate the `MIN` or `MAX`, which is why your current index is not used efficiently.

---

> I need to rapidly do select queries on it in a loop

Are you sure that you need to query in a loop? Have you considered moving the loop into the database? Maybe what you really need is a join? It's better to send a single query that fetches a lot of data than lots of small queries that fetch only a small amount of data each.

Comment: i just added the output of show index to my post. Can you please take a look to see if anything looks wrong? also, you're suggesting a create a second compound index right?

Comment: yes indexing is best option for improving and speed up operation in mysql qureies.

Comment: @xendi: You didn't say what the other index is for.

Comment: i also have this one: SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `04c1Tg0M` WHERE `tried` = 0;

Comment: @xendi: There is no particular optimization for `COUNT ... WHERE` apart from counting the rows, and that requires `O(n)` time. Adding an index on `tried` may help a small amount, but the query will still require time proportional to the count. Assuming a 50/50 split between `tried = 0` and `tried = 1` this will only give you a 50% speed up. Could you consider a completely different approach instead? Perhaps you could cache the result instead of asking for it multiple times?

Comment: aah thats true. I could grab the count once and then keep track of the count with a variable that I modify every time I remove a row from the table.

Comment: @xendi: Yes, that would be much more efficient. But why do you remove rows one at a time? Did you know you can remove multiple rows in a single query?

Comment: i know. its just that i have to perform some operations on the data in each row before I know if it should be deleted yet. I may consider doing them in batches.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an index on the `tried` column should speed up your queries.
MySQL uses indexes for these operations:

To find the MIN() or MAX() value for a specific indexed column key_col. This is optimized by a preprocessor that checks whether you are using WHERE key_part_N = constant on all key parts that occur before key_col in the index. In this case, MySQL does a single key lookup for each MIN() or MAX() expression and replaces it with a constant. If all expressions are replaced with constants, the query returns at once. For example:

SELECT MIN(key_part2),MAX(key_part2) FROM tbl_name WHERE key_part1=10;

Answer (score 0):

If you add an index on the `tried` column, your query should speed up.

You can use a command like

```
create index tried_ix1 on 04c1Tg0M (tried);
```

As a side note, if you are applying an index on an InnoDb table, please also consider whether or not this index should be clustered. For example, if you are going to access a lot of the tables record's, in a particular, perhaps sorted, order, for perhaps a report, then consider creating a clustered index based on the sorting requirements of that report.